# How does `npm outdated -g` actually work?

Tags: npm, npm-update, npm-outdated

I have some globally installed packages and I want to update some of them. I checked with

```
$ npm outdated -g
Package                 Current  Wanted  Latest  Location
eslint                   5.16.0  5.16.0   6.8.0  global
jshint                   2.10.2  2.11.0  2.11.0  global
n                        2.1.12  2.1.12   6.2.0  global
npx                      10.2.0  10.2.2  10.2.2  global
```

I tried

```
$ npm update -g eslint --dd
```

but I got the message

```
outdated not updating eslint because it's currently at the maximum version that matches its specified semver range
```

I checked the documentation with

```
$ npm help outdated
```

> - **wanted** is the maximum version of the package that satisfies the
>     semver range specified in **package.json**. If there's no available semver
>     range (i.e.  you're running **npm outdated --global**, or the package isn't included in **package.json**), then **wanted** shows the currently-installed version.

But that's obviously not true because

```
$ npm update -g jshint
```

worked and the values of `Current` and `Wanted` for the package `jshint` were different before the update. How is the value of `wanted` actually defined?

Sidequestion: What is the npm-way to update all outdated packages and what is the npm-way to update one package?

**EDIT:**

To check if it's related to major and minor version numbers I installed

```
$ npm install -g n@6.1.0
$ npm install -g eslint@6.7.0
$ npm install -g generator-wombytes-cpp@0.2.0
```

and I updated the other packages. Now the output is

```
$ npm outdated -g
Package                 Current  Wanted  Latest  Location
eslint                    6.7.0   6.8.0   6.8.0  global
generator-wombytes-cpp    0.2.0   0.2.0   0.3.0  global
n                         6.1.0   6.2.0   6.2.0  global
```

There is a different behavior for these packages.

Comment: `eslint`'s latest version `6.8.0` is a [MAJOR](https://semver.org/) update from `5.16.0`, i.e. it has incompatible API changes with the current version - hence the message. Whilst `jshint`'s latest `2.11.0` is a MINOR update from `2.10.2`, i.e. it has added functionality in a backwards compatible manner.  Presumably you get a similar message when running `npm update -g n` ?

Comment: @RobC I added some information to my question. As you can see `npm` would update some packages but wouldn't update one other package. Why? And why doesn't it behave as documented? Is it a bug?

Comment: See related issues [#746](https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/746) and [#755](https://github.com/npm/cli/pull/755) - whether it's a bug or incorrect documentation is yet to be determined. IMHO it's the latter (incorrect docs). After the edit you made, i.e. installing specific versions to check if related to minor/major versions, presumably when you next run e.g. `npm update -g <pkg_name>` for each one it updates them all to the version listed in the _Latest_ column because there is no `MAJOR` diffs between _Current_ and _Latest_ unlike your previous examples?